# The best practices for running CloudFunctions regularly based on the timestamp of each user

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We are developing an app on Flutter on the client side and Firebase on the server side. I'm thinking of running Cloud Functions regularly using Cloud Scheduler based on each user's timestamp.
My idea is to run Cloud Functions using Cloud Scheduler every day at 12:00. Only users who have a timestamp older than 10 days perform a specific action. Is this a best practice?

Or is it possible to process Cloud Functions using the user's timestamp as a trigger?
For example, Cloud Functions is triggered when 10 days have passed since the user's timestamp.

**Update**
The scenario is as follows.

Cloud Firestore

```
/user/${userId}/funcStatus/status
```

Document(status) field is

```
timestamp:last update date(e.g. 2019/10/31)
```

I want to execute Cloud Function after 10 days, that is, when it becomes 11/10.
 However, the timestamp varies depending on the user. e.g, userA:10/31, userB:10/20

Comment: What do you mean by a user's timestamp?  Can you try and explain the logical function you want to achieve?  Try paint a scenario picture ... when this happens this that happens for example.

Comment: I added details!

Comment: @Doug Stevenson has given what I would have suggested ... which is to create a Cloud Task that fires 10 days after the original input message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option is possible with [scheduled functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).

The second option is not possible with scheduled functions alone.  You would have to use a Firestore onCreate trigger, then set up a callback with [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/) to get the function to execute at the right time.

Whichever one you choose is a matter of preference and whatever meets the needs of your app.  There is no right or wrong way.